# Jquery assign second child attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a way to assign nested div attribute with variable? Like

```
<div>
  <div>
    123456
  </div>
</div>
```

Become

```
<div>
  <div sectionid="123">
    123456
  </div>
</div>
```

BTW above component will be created by JavaScript.

I've tried something like this, but it didn't work.

```
var a = $('<div><div>123456</div></div>');
a.eq(":nth-child(2)").attr("sectionid", "123");
```

Comment: your `a` var has 2 seperate divs - not a nested one and it wouldn't be the second child if it nested - it would be the first.  Also `.eq` takes an index, which should be an integer - not a selector

Comment: Are you trying to select an element that already exists and update it? If you pass a string of html to the `$()` function the way you are that creates *new* elements (that are not part of the DOM).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this snippet.

```js
//FOR DOM HTML
console.log("FOR DOM HTML");
//1st way
$('#input > div').find('div').attr("sectionid","123");
console.log($('#input').html());
//2nd way
$('#input > div > div').attr("sectionid","321");
console.log($('#input').html());


//JS HTML
console.log("FOR JS OBJECT");
var input = $('<div><div>123456</div></div>');
//1st way
input.eq(0).children().attr('sectionid', '456');
console.log(input[0].outerHTML);
var input = $('<div><div>123456</div></div>');
//2nd way
$(input[0]).children().attr('sectionid', '789');
console.log(input[0].outerHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="input">
<div>
  <div>
    123456
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, very great, step by step walkthrough.

Comment: @CodaChang your welcome, great to see that it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

`nth-child(2)` maches elements that are the second child element of their parent. This is not the case for your div, it is the first element of the parent div.

`.eq` finds an element at a specific index. It is not the place to pass a selector.

The child selector, `>`, will find a child element, i.e. `div>div` will find a div that is an immediate child of a div.

Note that the code you've provided, `$('<div></div>123456<div></div>');`, doesn't create a DOM tree like the one you've pasted.

**Update**, now that the code is edited, the value of `a` is a div with a child div. Since `a.find` will perform a search within  `a`, you don't have to use a child selector, but can find the div immediately:

```
a.find('div')
```

Comment: Not if the OP is trying to update an element already in the DOM (because `a` refers to new elements not in the DOM and not in the same structure as described in the first part of the question).

Comment: @nnnnnn: True. I'm still guessing that the child selector is what's being asked for, but I didn't notice at first that the value of `a` doesn't match OP's description.

Comment: Yep. You're obviously right about the child selector. Not sure if the OP also wants to find a specific child div with that "123456" content, but anyway...maybe they'll respond to the comments up above.

Comment: I typed wrongly, it's `var a = $('<div><div>123456</div></div>');`

Answer (score 1):

Just apply attribute to children. No complicated 'find', eq(), etc.

```js
var a = $('<div><div>123456</div></div>');

a.children().attr('sectionid', '123');
$('body').append(a);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you add it in the first place? Not clear if you add it later!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var sectionid = "123";
  var a = $('<div><div sectionid="' + sectionid + '">123456</div></div>');
  $('body').append(a);
});
```

```css
div[sectionid]{
  color: red;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this - I have added comments to the code to explain what is happening.

Inspect the element to see that the attribute is added

```js
var a = $('<div><div>123456</div></div>'); // change this to match the structure you want

a.children() // .children gets the direct descendant (which should be the nested div
  .eq(0) // gets the first in the array that is returned (if there are multiple direct descendents) - it is a 0 based index selector
  .attr('sectionid', '123');

$('body').append(a)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

[More information about .children()](https://api.jquery.com/children/)

[More information about .eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)

Answer (score 0):

try it :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("div").eq(1).attr("sectionid","123");

})
```